# Solving $2^x \equiv x \pmod {11}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Solve  $ 2^x \equiv x \pmod {11}$.

I know 2 is a primitive root modulo 11.

So. I get $x \equiv \operatorname{ind}_2x \pmod {10}$

And I'm stuck!

(Maybe I can $x=1$, $x=2$, $x=3$, and so on... but looking for brilliant method.)

Could you give me some advice?

Is 'primitive root' useful thing for solving this type?

Thanks in advance.

$$
$$
**P.S.**

And I'd like to check this via http://wolframalpha.com

but this show.... http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%5Ex++mod11+%3Dx

I wanna know proper command for check this problem.

maybe not [ 2^x  mod11 =x ]

Comment: I suggest trial and error

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Thank you for your comment. And you mean substitution for x?

Comment: I think you mean $x\equiv \text{ind}_2(x)$?

Comment: @DavidPeterson Really thank you. I edited :-)

Comment: [Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=values+%282%5En+-+n%29%2F11+for+n+%3D1+to+10)

Comment: @QuangHoang Really thank you. [wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=values+%282%5En+-+n%29%2F11+for+n+%3D1+to+65) Umm.. what is the rule?? Umm...

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is no non-brute-force method to solve this type of congruence.

Comment: @GregMartin You mean 'there is no general method solving this type', isn't it?

Comment: Of course there is a general method, namely, systematic evaluation of all possible answers. I think @Greg is saying this is the only general method.

Comment: @GregMartin: Can you back this up with some explanation/heuristic?

Comment: @QuangHoang: See the answer by Thjis below to see why your wolfram computation is incorrect.

Comment: @RghtHndSd It's almost the same problem as the discrete log problem, which is used in some cryptography because there are no general heuristics for solving it quickly.

Comment: I retract my earlier statement about there being no nice method - Barry Cipra's answer (building on Thijs's observations) is quite nice.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using Fermats little theorem, it follows that $2^x\equiv2^{x \mod 10}$. This should be equal to $x\mod11$. The residue classes are from $x\equiv0$ to $x\equiv9$: $$1;2;4;8;5;10;9;7;3;6;$$

This should be equal to the residue class $x\mod11$. Using the Chinese remainder theorem:
\begin{align}
x\equiv0\mod 10\qquad &x\equiv1&\mod11\implies &x\equiv100&\mod110\\
x\equiv1\mod 10\qquad &x\equiv2&\mod11\implies &x\equiv101&\mod110\\
x\equiv2\mod 10\qquad &x\equiv4&\mod11\implies &x\equiv92&\mod110\\
x\equiv3\mod 10\qquad &x\equiv8&\mod11\implies &x\equiv63&\mod110\\
x\equiv4\mod 10\qquad &x\equiv5&\mod11\implies &x\equiv104&\mod110\\
x\equiv5\mod 10\qquad &x\equiv10&\mod11\implies &x\equiv65&\mod110\\
x\equiv6\mod 10\qquad &x\equiv9&\mod11\implies &x\equiv86&\mod110\\
x\equiv7\mod 10\qquad &x\equiv7&\mod11\implies &x\equiv7&\mod110\\
x\equiv8\mod 10\qquad &x\equiv3&\mod11\implies &x\equiv58&\mod110\\
x\equiv9\mod 10\qquad &x\equiv6&\mod11\implies &x\equiv39&\mod110\\
\end{align}

The given residue classes $\mod110$ are the answer to the question.

Comment: I think everyone else who looked at this question assumed it would only depend on $x$ modulo 11, including myself. Great work!

Comment: Don't you mean mod $110$ instead of $121$?

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing this out, @Greg thanks for editing.

Comment: Wow.. Really great!! wow....... wow.. both modulo 10 and 11...!!! Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 1):

This is Mathematica code. I believe that it will work on Wolfram Alpha.

```
m = 11;
Select[Range[m], Mod[2^#, m] == # &]
{7}
```

For large values of $m$ this will be faster

```
m = 1234567;
Select[Range[m], PowerMod[2, #, m] == # &]
{313692}
```

After reading the comments and Thijx answer, I propose the following code:

```
m = 11;
xmax = EulerPhi[m]m;
Select[Range[xmax], Mod[2^# - #, m] == 0 &]
{7, 39, 58, 63, 65, 86, 92, 100, 101, 104}
```

Comment: Can you explain the code please?

Comment: I acknowledge it is quite cryptical. `Range[m]` is $\{1,\dots,m\}$. `Mod[2^a,b]=PowerMod[2,a,b]` computes $2^a\mod b$. The `#`, `&` construction is a _pure function_. `#` is the argument. It returns `True` if the equality holds, `False` if not. `Select` selects the values in `Range[m]` returning `True`.

Comment: I see. I will edit the code.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a$ be any nonnegative integer and let $k=a-2^a$.  Let $x=a+10k$.  Then, using a mixture of unconditional equality and mod-$11$ congruence, we have

$$2^x=2^{a+10k}\equiv2^a=a-(a-2^a)=a-k\equiv a+10k=x$$

This doesn't give every solution, but it does give an infinite family of solutions (all negative).  For example, $a=1$ gives $2^{-9}\equiv-9$ mod $11$.

**Added later**:  In light of Thijs's complete solution, it's worth noting that the explicit formula here, which can be written as

$$x=11a-10\cdot2^a$$

gives, for $a=0,1,2,\ldots,9$, the values $-10,-9,-18,\ldots,-5021$, which agree mod $110$ with the residues in Thijs's Chinese remainder theorem results, *in the exact same order*, i.e., $-10\equiv100$, $-9\equiv101$, $-18\equiv92,\ldots,-5021\equiv39$ mod $110$.  Presumably this generalizes in some fashion to something like

$$x\equiv q^x\text{ mod } p\iff x\equiv pa-(p-1)q^a\text{ mod }p(p-1)\text{ for some }a\in\mathbb{N}$$